# Extracting element from a string

Tags: r, string, text, data-cleaning, grepl

Im trying to extract a element between two HTML tags without any packages.

Say I have a string:

```
string <- c("<tb example", "<TEXT>", "some text", "<TEXT>", "<TEXT> some more text <TEXT>")
```

I want to extract the element (some text) that is between the first two TEXT elements.

I have tried to use grelp and gregexpr, but cant get this to work.

```
string[grepl("<TEXT>(.*?)<TEXT>", string, ignore.case = F)]
regmatches(string,gregexpr("<TEXT>", string, ignore.case = F))
```

Thanks

Comment: Correct code for the string: string <- c("<tb example", "<TEXT>", "some text", "<TEXT>", "<TEXT> some more text <TEXT>")

Comment: For these tasks I use `gsub` and standard regex grouping. Something of the sort `gsub("(.*TEXT)(sometext)(TEXT.*)", \\2,string)`

Comment: if you are working with `vector` then you can also get the string by index `string[3]` (given your `vector` structure is fixed).

Answer (score 2):

The regex concept will not work here because you have a vector, not a string. An idea for doing this on a vector can be to identify the first two `<TEXT>`, use `seq` to complete the sequence, and then `setdiff` to isolate the desired value, i.e.

```
v1 <- which(string == '<TEXT>')[1]
v2 <- which(string == '<TEXT>')[2]

string[setdiff(seq(v1, v2), c(v1, v2))]
#[1] "some text"
```

Comment: It gives an error if <TEXT> does not appear at all.

Answer (score 1):

First concatenate your strings vector into one string, then use `stringr` package for regex

```
library(stringr)

string <- c("<tb example", "<TEXT>", "some text", "<TEXT>", "<TEXT> some more text <TEXT>")
string_c <- paste(string, collapse = " ")

# Find the first occurrence
res <- str_match(string_c, "<TEXT> (.*?) <TEXT>")

res[2]
#[1] "some text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Except for 3a these assume that you are looking for the first length 3 subsequence of `string` of the form `<TEXT>` something `<TEXT>`; however, if any number of vector components of `string` are allowed between successive `<TEXT>` components then use 3a or 4a.

**1)** If `string` has at least 3 elements, create a three column moving window matrix `m` and calculate a logical vector `ok` which is TRUE for rows in which columns 1 and 3 equal `<TEXT>`.  Take the first element of the second column of `m` having a row for which  `ok` is TRUE.

If there are no matches then this code returns a zero length character vector.  No packages are used.

```
m <- embed(string, 3)
ok <- !rowSums(m[, -2, drop = FALSE] != "<TEXT>")
head(m[ok, 2], 1)
## [1] "some text"
```

**2)** A variation of the above is, for each row of `e`, to return the middle element if the first and last elements are `<TEXT>` and NA otherwise.
Then remove the NAs and take the first element of what is left.

```
e <- embed(string, 3)
Select <- function(x) ifelse(all(x[-2] == "<TEXT>"), x[2], NA)
head(na.omit(apply(e, 1, Select)), 1)
## [1] "some text"
```

**3)** Another base approach is to create a grouping vector `g` of the same length as `string` which increases by 1 each time `<TEXT>` is encountered.  Then use `tapply` to extract the second element of each group that has length 2 or NA if other length.  Remove the NA elements and take the first of what is left.  It returns a zero length character vector if there are no matching subsequences.

```
g <- cumsum(string == "<TEXT>")
Select2 <- function(x) if (length(x) == 2) x[2] else NA
ta <- tapply(string[g > 0], g[g > 0], Select2)
as.character(head(na.omit(c(ta)), 1))
## [1] "some text"
```

**3a)** If more than one component of `string` is allowable between `<TEXT>` components then modify this the following.  It returns NULL if there are no matching subsequences.

```
g <- cumsum(string == "<TEXT>")
ta <- tapply(string[g > 0], g[g > 0], function(x) x[-1], simplify = FALSE)
unname(unlist((head(ta, 1))))
## [1] "some text"
```

**4)** This finds the element after each `<TEXT>` elements and picks out the first one of those. If there is only one `<TEXT>` it returns the element after it and returns a 0 length character vector if there are no `<TEXT>` elements at all or if the only `<TEXT>` element appears at the end of the input vector.

```
head(string[c(FALSE, head(string, -1) == "<TEXT>")], 1)
## [1] "some text"
```

**4a)** If more than one element can appear between `<TEXT>` elements then use this instead. Note that this returns NULL if fewer than two `<TEXT>` elements exist.  Add an `else` leg to the `if` if iyou want to return something else in that case.

```
ix <- head(which(string == "<TEXT>"), 2)
if (length(ix) == 2) string[seq(ix[1] + 1, ix[2] - 1)]
## [1] "some text"
```

Comment: thank you for your great explanation! However, I found a easier way. string <- grep("<TEXT>", string)[1:2]
string[text.range[1]:text.range[2]]

Comment: I have added 4a since there still has been no clarification on whether more than one intervening element is allowed.  Overall I think 4 or 4a  are preferable.  They give the correct answer and they work even if there are no `<TEXT>` elements.  Neither of these is true for the code in your comment.